# Why can't the right part of this conditional type be never?

Tags: typescript

I have a rule to enforce at type-checking time on the parameters that can be passed to my function.

The type is (I left comments to explain the iterations I went through):

```
type CheckConf<TConf extends SupportedConf> = {
  // this seems intuitively correct but doesn't work, propabably an issue with capturing values
  // [Key in keyof TConf]: readonly [Key, readonly [Key, Key]];

  // Extract will only match if the record value matches the pattern. It works well to reject the whole entry
  //   [Key in keyof TConf]: Extract<
  //     TConf[Key],
  //     readonly [Key, readonly [Key, Key]]
  //   >;

  // this works better to get to the error at the tuple index level
  [Key in keyof TConf]: TConf[Key] extends SupportedConf[string]
    ? [Key, [Key, Key]]
    : // This is necessary in this context even if I don't understand why it works. My intuition
      // would be to have `never`
      TConf[Key]; ⬅⬅⬅
};
```

And is used like that:

```
declare function check<TConf extends SupportedConf>(
  // following would work to get a global error on the whole conf but we wnt more targetted errors
  // params: TConf extends CheckConf<TConf> ? TConf : never

  params: CheckConf<TConf>
): TConf[keyof TConf];

check({ a: ["a", ["a", "a"]], b: ["b", ["b", "b"]] });

check(
  // @ts-expect-error
  { a: ["a", ["a", "b"]] }
);

// @ts-expect-error
check({ a: ["a", true] });
```

Here's a [live playground for the whole thing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHcAsFMDtQM4AdoGMCWAzAnu2BzUAQ3mgA8AXOAEwVFQBsiBXBaUPUCmUfOaAE7pUxJAKIBbaFQGhqaJuIroA9vHQUOCAFAgOEpCoEUSmiitCwVmzEb6aB0ItTUNsoW7IrMkDdtZgBKHQ2YgYGLh5wIwBrOTV2ACN3VjxCAAMACiIEAEp6NQQKdK1QZlgXWGhtCmwUUABlH0NjaGoAYTVMUABeUAAlNCNqAB5tUEQKIQIAGnHQR2dXdwBtIun8GYWnSrdQNam0rfW0gF1T7QA%20AG5tXTBa%20oBZbCeiJBRqAEkKuGVakYAFUGqGGoHIVAqdCaHyMVA6XUuvVAAG97hN9gBpaDuTgxHEqbrAoYCainABcoGJoNJK2x2FOtz0AF9buj5IwiI4POVUMo1BxfrB-tgRqDYEUqSCwRCaNDmnC2p1YJhLpl0RMkFzJAhKdThujcpSGugDAwsKL9aSbndHux2jBUDFlZggS7wZQ5Y0Fa0ESqkX00RM9NwQohoNAJHQ8N4NOgAG7QPY0xx80CJZiaFzQBCwADkmmiAhiWzEKi1iSIiT2JC0CGY7HAGkg9He3g2oHjRAYDZ0wbAdJxgtA%20OwhKpLop2yWsD2g%20wW0Wu1W9K29PObP7oAAopRxGmm%20FQMtQBIiBRUC2sJF2KmwV2e%20wzxeYHRuOwtRQZLAAHSgL6FrEdDgEmETmNsABWaBmFEkAqH44LCgI2DzHoEzzsOo7joCk6UruUxEHyYxbhiE5dPOpxzCRGJLie86LjsdGrqA64XNRNqoQ8kBhkWMR0Ik0gyFwFj2MJN7ggIAhGMQMHsN4vjsHg8hkKAfiJgw8wYXiBJErhZEqhRHqQrQ3qwr6LoHBsbEYgA-FiOJbPRLE4uc8wTJSeiAtx0Z0FUqA5ggXK4vAoZ0OKVCUOCibqN0XzxPmmjlPIAhFCQ1AQJAuKAcWCB-i8gqZnGahuRiejRMwDDpQJYmQEQiagOkVSJgI6QlRMOHkeutysncHKKOwmC8vy8CXmgMRul0RlejCLTwi6aqcR48EMCoTYEBAKgVelvFiaJRC8CtlYRIIUmyAK74ZfB7Dit0GaFo2wqnkYclcvY8ISadfagHoWriFGerurKUKgA6Y0uhN-qgHZHUqqAlJNYIdyatq-0g46zpdBDqraEa%20mYCsWG6V0jJ3KNTqZCixCUisABERA045dMM6ATPnFsiTUzTiTM7T3NbFzNPnKAzK5GyZMxOqW4AAIUAgAC05AoHyCuSUY8yU0QnP04z2ss9zQvMjjbJ6DL8uK9BKundo4sU1T%20xM1sUwNqcwui9oQA)

I managed to get the `CheckConf` type to work correctly. The part I struggled with was the right side of the conditional. Intuitively I initially put `never` because my reasoning is that if the given type doesn't even pass the `extends` check, it means it is wrong anyway. But it generates a false positive.

What is the theory to explain this behaviour, and why `never` is not the right thing to put here?

Comment: @jcalz my bad, I'm struggling with my left and my right  but indeed it made no sense

Comment: I am still confused by what you're doing... the code you have lets you call `check(10)`; is that intentional?  Why is this not written like `declare function check<S extends string>(param: readonly [S, \`${S}-augmented\`]): void;`? What is the generic conditional type doing for you?

Comment: @jcalz I oversimplified the example, trying to reduce it as much as possible, but it is now confusing indeed. Let me edit the question with a more exhaustive example.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to get a [mre] that isn't *too* minimal.  I have to admit I'm not sure what's going on that causes it to fail to infer with `never` there; I don't know the details of inferring `T` from a value of type `T extends U ? F<T> : G<T>`, and usually I'd avoid doing that unless I had to.  So right now I can't answer the question and might not be able to do so even if you augment the example.  (In other words: don't go too crazy expanding the example for me)

Comment: @jcalz I finally found the time to refine my question with a more complete example. Ignore the "stupidity" of the check that just enforce that all the value in the tuples matches the configuration key, in real life, it is more complicated than that, but that's the spirit.

Answer (score 0):

> my reasoning is that if the given type doesn't even pass the extends check, it means it is wrong anyway

```
type Check<T extends readonly [string, string]> = T extends readonly [string, string]
  ? readonly [T[0], `${T[0]}-augmented`]
  : never;
```

In the above example, your reasoning may make sense but this will make the type somehow ugly and weird however in your example

```js
type Check<T> = T extends readonly [string, string]
  ? readonly [T[0], `${T[0]}-augmented`]
  : T;
```

`T` can be anything (as `string[]` where you encountered the error) and your type depends on it, therefore makes sense to check if it extends `readonly [string, string]` so the type is `readonly [T[0], ${T[0]}-augmented]` otherwise it is `T` the same type of the given generic type

that's what your code is doing, I hope this clarifies things